# creating jms config on activemq with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jms, activemq-classic

I am a newbie one at JMS on ApacheMq. Can Java Messaging Service and Apache MQ can be integrated or have a config with MySQL without using KahaDB as a default database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can define a new data store: http://activemq.apache.org/how-to-configure-a-new-database.html. Somewhere in there is probably the way to turn off KahaDB, too.